# Error passing variables using a form php>form>php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Please whats wrong with this code?

Im using it to add some data to database but im getting empty `$toid` and `$toname` when trying to insert.

This is the form. The variables `$toid` and `$toname` are ok here.

```
//write new message
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == compose) { 
        if (isset($_GET['toid'])) {
            $toid = $_GET['toid'];
            $tosql = "select * from authors where id =".$toid.""; 
            $toquery = mysql_query($tosql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
            $torow = mysql_fetch_array($toquery);   
            $toname = $torow['displayname'];
        if (isset($_GET['subject'])) { $subject = $_GET['subject']; }
        if (isset($_GET['message'])) { 
            $message = $_GET['message']; 
            echo "<h3>Replying</h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>Replying to ".$toname.".</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>".$subject."".nl2br($message)."<br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table><br />Type your answer:<br /><br />";
        } else { echo "New message"; }
        echo "<form action=\"mail.php?action=send\" method=post>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>To:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"to\" size=\"50\" value=\"".$toname."\"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title:</td><td><input type=text name=subject size=50 value=".$subject."></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign=\"top\">Message:</td><td><textarea  rows=\"10\" cols=\"70\" name=\"message\"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=\"right\" colspan=\"2\"><input id=\"submitstyle\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar Mensagem\"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>"; 
        }
}
```

Here is the code to insert the message to databse, the `$toid` and `$toname` are empty here. Its suposed to being retrieved from the form above, right?

```
//send message  
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == send) { 

    if ($subject == "" || $message == "") {
        header('Location: mail.php?action=compose&toid='.$toid.'&subject=\''.$subject.'\'&sendpm=false');
        exit(); 
    }

    $date = DATE(YmdHis); 

    echo $userid."from<br />to".$toid."<br />toname".$toname;

    $sendsql = "INSERT INTO mail (sender, reciever, subject, message, created_at, status, sender_deleted, reciever_deleted) 
                        VALUES (".$userid.", ".$toid.", ".$subject.", ".$message.", ".$date.",unread, 0, 0)"; 
    $sendquery = mysql_query($sendsql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div class=\"alert\" style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 13px;\"><b>Mensagem particular enviada com sucesso!</b></div>
            <br /><table align=\"center\" width=\"75%\" class=\"sortable\">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2' style=\"text-align:center;font-weight:normal;\">Mensagem particular enviada para ".$toname.".</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        Title: ".$subject."
                        Message: ".nl2br($message)."

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>";
}
```

Im also getting this sql error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' RE: assunto3, 3, 20121017023723,unread, 0, 0)'` at line 2 wich i think its because of the empty variables mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass those variables as hidden form values: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm

Then you need to get the variables from the form via $_POST.

Try $toid = $_POST['toid'] and $toname = $_POST['toname']. But be wary about SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Don't just accept values blindly from $_POST. Be sure to validate and filter them first.

Or if toid/toname aren't changable by the user, why not just requery for them?

Comment: toname is being retrieved from another table... i will try using the hidden values. thanks.

Comment: worked, thanks, the vars are being passed ok now.. the sql error was persisting because of quotes problems, wich i solved following the other answers. Since your answer solved the major issue i will accept it. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `INSERT` values, and put strings in quotes:

```
$sendsql = 'INSERT INTO mail (sender, reciever, subject, message, created_at, status, sender_deleted, reciever_deleted) 
            VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($userid).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($toid).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($subject).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($message).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($date).'","unread", 0, 0)';
```

Also, be sure you always **escape the values** that are immediately used in SQL queries from $_GET or $_POST. Otherwise, you are most likely to experience SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

You need to write SQL Statement in php like that:

```
 $tosql = "select * from authors where id ='$toid'";
```

and

```
 $sendsql = "INSERT INTO mail (sender, reciever, subject, message, created_at, status, sender_deleted, reciever_deleted) 
                    VALUES ('$userid', '$toid', '$subject', '$message', '$date', 'unread', 0, 0)";
```

i think this will be help you.